# Infinite Scroll not working on Firefox, but works on Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have discovered that my implementation of infinite scroll *does not work on Firefox*, but it does work on Safari and Chrome. (I am using Vue.js, and the problem is that I cannot figure out how to devise a boolean expression to discern if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the window that works on Firefox. Here is the methods section, in the script area of the .vue file of the main component:

```
 methods: {
    bottomVisible() {
      /**
       * This solution doesn't work for firefox
       */
      const scrollY = window.scrollY
      const visible = document.documentElement.clientHeight
      const pageHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight
      const bottomOfPage = visible + scrollY >= pageHeight
      console.log(bottomOfPage || pageHeight < visible);
      return bottomOfPage || pageHeight < visible;
    },
    addMoreCards() {
      this.$store.dispatch(
        "increaseMultiplier",
        this.$store.state.cardToShowMultiplier + 1
      );
    }
  },
  watch: {
    bottom(bottom) {
      if (bottom) {
        this.addMoreCards();
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      this.bottom = this.bottomVisible();
    });
  }
};
```

The biggest problem is that when I inspect the console in Firefox, this line never prints True: `console.log(bottomOfPage || pageHeight < visible);`

***Can anyone help me find a find create a new boolean that would return True if the user scrolls to the bottom of the page on Firefox, Safari, and Chrome***, allowing me to call the function `addMoreCards()` when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page? I certainly am not a front-end developer, so I could really use you guys' help!

Here are some other tidbits that may be of use:

- Sometimes, in FireFox, scrolling to the bottom of the page will cause `bottomVisible()` to return `True` as intended. However, it will not consistently work. When it does, I do get this warning in the console:

`This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning; see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects for further details and to join the discussion on related tools and features!`

- In Firefox, the infinite scroll appears to work better if I make the window more narrow, though still not consistently. Not sure why...

Comment: Can you log the values of `visible`, `scrollY`, and `pageHeight`? That will probably explain what’s going on. (Also, I’d do this with an [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) on an element at the bottom of the page, with that element being a manual “load more” link too.)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, with the help from the comment above. After logging the values of the variables, it seems that Mozilla's scrollY values are .5 less than it should be. To fix this, I simply added .5 to the scrollY value, so that `const bottomOfPage = visible + scrollY >= pageHeight` would be set to `true` when at the bottom.